# launch browser(safari)inside my app

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I have the following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"workingUrl"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

which currently loads the url correctly but when the user is done, they have to exit and go back into my app.

How can the browser be loaded from within my app?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a little browser yourself.  Create a View Controller with a `UIWebView` and some buttons that tigger it's methods (forward, back, reload, etc).

Comment: How is rotation handled? All I really want to do is load video clips from vimeo or Youtube. If the user is watching a video and turns the device, is that still handled by the video player on the iphone?
regards

Comment: Oh, in that case you don't need a "browser" at all.  Just a webview, opened to the URL with a youtube widget in it.  THe user taps the youtube widget and the play pops up.  I believe rotation is handled for you and all works as expected.